# Play 2.0 routes file for different configurations

Tags: configuration, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.0 application with 3 different configurations (application.conf, test.conf and prod.conf)

Now I have a robots.txt file that should be delivered for only test.conf and for the rest environments it should give a 404 if someone tries to access it.

How can I configure my routes file to check if my application is using test.conf? Can I set some variable in test.conf that I can check in the routes file?

Something like this? (pseudo code)

```
#{if environment = "test"}
GET     /robots.txt                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="robots.txt")
#{/if}
#{else}
GET     /robots.txt                 controllers.Application.notFoundResult()
#{/else}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add logic in the `routes` file.

I'd write a controller to serve the `robots.txt` file. Something like this:

In the `routes` file:

```
GET /robots.txt   controllers.Application.robots
```

Then, in the controller, I'll test if I'm in a testing environment :

```
def robots = Action {
    if (environment == "test") { // customize with your method
      Redirect(routes.Assets.at("robots.txt"))    
    } else {
      NotFound("")
    }
}
```

I'm using Scala, but it can be easily translated to Java.

#### Edit - java sample

You can check if application is in one of three states: `prod`, `dev` or `test`, ie, simple method returning current state:

```
private static String getCurrentMode() {
    if (play.Play.isTest()) return "test";
    if (play.Play.isDev()) return "dev";
    if (play.Play.isProd()) return "prod";
    return "unknown";
}
```

you can use as:

```
play.Logger.debug("Current mode: "+ getCurrentMode());
```

of course in your case that's enough to use these condition directly:

```
public static Result robots() {
    return (play.Play.isProd())
            ? notFound()
            : ok("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
}
```

Comment: What is `Play.current.mode` and how do I set it to "Test"? Or any other arbitrary value (like "Staging")?

Comment: I edited my answer. `Play.current.mode` is used to check if Play is started in Dev, Prod or Test mode (ie, `play run`, `play start` or `play test`).

Comment: Where can I read more about these modes? And when and how to use them? For instance mode `test` seems to run the JUnit tests (but doesn't actually run the Play server) So I can't define an action that checks for `test`...

Comment: These are built in modes. I don't think they fit your need. Forget about these, and create your own method which checks the environment you are in, as explained in my edited answer.

Comment: @PeterWarbo check my edit for Java sample - for test or dev returns robots dissalowing indexing and `404` for production state

Comment: @biesior thanks for your addition, though your suggestion is not helping me because isTest() is only true when running unit tests. I solved it by creating my own property in the conf file like test.conf has a property named env=test and prod.conf has env=prod so I can check this property at runtime...